# Task fromAsync timeout

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I have this piece of code to make an asynchronous HTTP request:

```
    public static void MakeRequest(Uri uri, Action<RequestCallbackState> responseCallback)
    {
        WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(uri);
        request.Proxy = null;

        Task.Factory.FromAsync<WebResponse>(request.BeginGetResponse, request.EndGetResponse, null).ContinueWith(task =>
            {
                WebResponse response = task.Result;
                Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
                responseCallback(new RequestCallbackState(response.GetResponseStream()));
                responseStream.Close();
                response.Close();
            });
    }
```

It works, but I need to set a request timeout. I tried to use request.Timeout but don't seem to do anything. Is there a way to set up a task timeout in this code?

Edited to add a new timeout callback.
New code:

```
    public static void MakeRequest(Uri uri, Action<RequestCallbackState> responseCallback)
    {
        WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(uri);
        request.Proxy = null;

        IAsyncResult t = Task.Factory.FromAsync<WebResponse>(request.BeginGetResponse, request.EndGetResponse, null).ContinueWith(task =>
            {
                WebResponse response = task.Result;
                Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
                responseCallback(new RequestCallbackState(response.GetResponseStream()));
                responseStream.Close();
                response.Close();
            });
        ThreadPool.RegisterWaitForSingleObject(t.AsyncWaitHandle, new WaitOrTimerCallback(TimeoutCallback), request, 1000, true);
    }

    private static void TimeoutCallback(object state, bool timedOut)
    {
        if (timedOut)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Timeout");
            WebRequest request = (WebRequest)state;
            if (state != null)
            {
                request.Abort();
            }
        }
    }
```

Testing with:

```
HttpSocket.MakeRequest(new Uri("http://www.google.comhklhlñ"), callbackState =>
    {
        if (callbackState.Exception != null)
            throw callbackState.Exception;
        Console.WriteLine(GetResponseText(callbackState.ResponseStream));
    });
Thread.Sleep(10000);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the [Timeout documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.timeout.aspx):

> The Timeout property has no effect on asynchronous requests made with the BeginGetResponse or BeginGetRequestStream method.

This is because the framework forces you to handle the timeout yourself.  You should be able to use the [example code here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.begingetresponse.aspx), except pass the `Task` returned from the `FromAsync` call to the `ThreadPool.RegisterWaitForSingleObject` method.

---

Edit:

You need to put the registration on the original task, not the continuation:

```
public static void MakeRequest(Uri uri, Action<Stream> responseCallback)
{
    WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(uri);
    request.Proxy = null;
    const int TimeoutPeriod = 1000;

    Task<WebResponse> t = Task.Factory.FromAsync<WebResponse>(request.BeginGetResponse, request.EndGetResponse, null);
    ThreadPool.RegisterWaitForSingleObject((t as IAsyncResult).AsyncWaitHandle, TimeoutCallback, request, TimeoutPeriod, true);
    t.ContinueWith(task =>
    {
        WebResponse response = task.Result;
        Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
        responseCallback(response.GetResponseStream());
        responseStream.Close();
        response.Close();
    });
}
```

This works for me (if I set the timeout duration very short, and hit this, I always timeout appropriately).

Comment: I changed the code as you can see in the question, but the timeout is not working. I only receive a callback with timedOut false and after that nothing happens.

Comment: I can't make it work. I have a thread.sleep in the main method. Could be this the problem? I updated the post to show you the code that I'm using to test it.

Comment: It throws only one time at the beginning with timedOut false.

Comment: I'm still stuck with this problem @Reed Could you help me? The code that you posted isn't working for me. I updated the question with all my code (main included). Could you take a look? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7372973/using-a-timeout-callback-in-async-requests Thanks for all your help.

Comment: @David: I answered there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7372973/using-a-timeout-callback-in-async-requests/7405109#7405109  It's the same answer as here, but a bit more explicit.  This technqiue works fine...