# Task.Factory.FromAsync and RegisterWaitForSingleObject - doesn't the latter kill the usefulness of the former?

Tags: .net, multithreading, asynchronous, io, timeout

The problem can be described by the following quote from MSDN:

> The CommandTimeout property will be ignored during asynchronous method
>   calls such as BeginExecuteReader.

Googling around for a solution for this problem I have stumbled upon a number of posts suggesting using `Task.Factory.FromAsync` in conjunction with `ThreadPool.RegisterWaitForSingleObject`.

On SO one can look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7368737/task-fromasync-timeout) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7372973/using-a-timeout-callback-in-async-requests/7405109#7405109), albeit those two discuss asynchronous web requests, rather than SQL commands. But the problem is all the same - timing out from an asynchronous SQL command/Web request.

The suggested approach is to call `Task.Factory.FromAsync` and then `ThreadPool.RegisterWaitForSingleObject` to wait or timeout on the handle corresponding to the task.

I do not understand something here. An async IO method is utilizing an IO completion port callback in order to return with the result. When such an IO operation starts, the calling thread returns back to the thread pool to be reused by other requests.

On the other hand, according to the MSDN:

> The RegisterWaitForSingleObject method queues the specified delegate to the thread pool

and

> The wait thread uses the Win32 WaitForMultipleObjects function to
>   monitor registered wait operations.

Which means it blocks a thread pool thread until our async IO returns or a timeout occurs. If my understanding is correct, having N async IOs in progress is going to block and lock N thread pool threads if we are using this technique.

But then, what is the point in using async IO under these circumstances? All the IOCP goodness is killed by `RegisterWaitForSingleObject`.

On the other hand, according to [this MSDN blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/02/06/10264610.aspx), `RegisterWaitForSingleObject` optimizes the wait, batching multiple handles from the same thread into one call to `WaitForMultipleObjects`, which in turns is limited with respect to amount of handles it can wait on - namely 64.

So how many thread pool threads are (b)locked if 65 async IO requests are made from the same thread in conjunction with `RegisterWaitForSingleObject` per each request?

Comment: It is pretty explicitly mentioned in the blog post "It could queue a work item to block on the handle, but that would end up burning a ThreadPool thread for each such call.  Instead..."

Comment: Yes, I was glad to discover that I understood the matter correctly **before** reading the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So how many thread pool threads are (b)locked if 65 async IO requests are made from the same thread in conjunction with RegisterWaitForSingleObject per each request?

Two (for the `RegisterWaitForSingleObject` calls) - each ThreadPool thread can handle 64 requests (technically, it's the value of `MAXIMUM_WAIT_OBJECTS`, which is 64 in practice).

> doesn't the latter kill the usefulness of the former?

No.  It does reduce it's effectiveness, but since there is a pooling of threads in `RegisterWaitForSingleObject`, it doesn't kill the usefulness.

Note that, in C# 5, I would typically use the `async`/`await` support with a timeout to handle this instead.  `Task.Delay` can be used to handle this simply, or you can make an [extension method using a Timer](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/11/10/10235834.aspx) to handle timeouts on any `Task`.